# expand/fill-in a Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, midi

I'm pretty new at Matlab so would need a baby-steps explanation.

I have some MIDI data which looks a bit like this:

time  on/off  note
10     1       61
90     0       61
90     1       72
92     1       87
100    0       72

What I want to do is expand or 'fill-in' the gaps so that I have a row for every single moment in time, and I have columns which show which notes are on (there is often more than one note at the same time).

the ultimate goal is to do some calculations about the overall relationship between notes on (the harmonic dissonance) at a given time.

So I was thinking that maybe I needed a new column for every single possible note (there are 127), and then a 1 or 0 for every time. Or maybe I can just have a matrix which just tells me which notes are on (so the number of columns varies).

I wrote my own pseudo-code, but have no idea how to implement it. I suspect there is a simple function that can do this. Here is my pseudo-code:

start with 0, at time 0 in a new 'notes-on matrix'
for numbers: 0 to n
    if the number matches a number in the time column, go to the on/off column for that row.
        if 1 in on/off column then copy number in notes column to 'notes-on matrix' for corresponding row
        if 0 then don't copy/do nothing.

if number doesn't match number in time column
 copy the previous row (which can be blank if there were no notes on).

for each row in the new 'notes-on matrix', arrange numbers low to high in different columns.

So can anyone tell me what to do?? I'm banging my head against a brick wall here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that will work even if the list is in a completely random order. It is based on the following idea: The cumulative sum of the vector `[0 1 0 0 -1 0 0]` is `[0 1 1 1 0 0 0]`. This corresponds to "on" in time 2, and "off" in time 5. Now all we need to do is populate an array with `1` and `-1`, and run [CUMSUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html) to transform it into an array that has, in each column, ones whenever the sound is `on`.

I assume that there are 128 notes (0-127), and that you want to have one time step of silence (if all notes eventually end) at the very end. Note that Matlab starts counting at 1, so time 0 corresponds to row #1.

```
%# midiData is a n-by-3 array with [time,on/off,note]
midiData = [...
10 1 61
90 0 61
90 1 72
92 1 87
100 0 72];

%# do not call unique here, because repeated input rows are relevant

%# note values can be from 0 to 127
nNotes = 128;

%# nTimepoints: find the highest entry in midiData's time-column
%# add 2, because midiData starts counting time at 0
%# and since we want to have one additional timepoint in the end
nTimepoints = max(midiData(:,1))+2; 




%# -- new solution ---
%# because the input is a bit messed up, we have to use a more complicated
%# solution. We'll use `accumarray`, with which we sum up all the
%# entries for on (+1) and off (-1) for each row(time)/column(note) pair.
%# after that, we'll apply cumsum

%# transform the input, so that 'off' is -1
%# wherever the second col of midiData is 0
%# replace it with -1
midiData(midiData(:,2)==0,2) = -1;

%# create output in one step
%# for every same coordinate (time,note), sum all the 
%# on/offs (@sum). Force the output to be 
%# a nTimepoints-by-nNotes array, and fill in zeros
%# where there's no information
output = accumarray(midiData(:,[1 3])+1,midiData(:,2),...
    [nTimepoints,nNotes],@sum,0);

%# cumsum, and we're done
output = cumsum(output,1);
```

The previous solution, for completeness:

```
%# --- old solution ---

 %# create output array, which we'll first populate with 1 and -1
%# after which we transform it into an on-off array
%# rows are timepoints, columns are notes
output = zeros(nTimepoints,nNotes);

%# find all on's 
%# onIdx is 1 if the second column of midiData is 1
onIdx = midiData(:,2) == 1;

%# convert time,note pairs into linear indices for
%# writing into output in one step
%# Add 1 to time and note, respectively, so that we start counting at 1
plusOneIdx = sub2ind([nTimepoints,nNotes],midiData(onIdx,1)+1,midiData(onIdx,3)+1);

%# write "1" wherever a note turns on
output(plusOneIdx) = 1;

%# now do the same for -1
offIdx = midiData(:,2) == 0;
minusOneIdx = sub2ind([nTimepoints,nNotes],midiData(offIdx,1)+1,midiData(offIdx,3)+1);

%# instead of overwrite the value in output, subtract 1
%# so that time/note that are both on and off become zeros
output(minusOneIdx) = output(minusOneIdx) - 1;

%# run cumsum on the array to transform the +1/-1 into stretches of 1 and 0
%# the 'dim' argument is 1, because we want to sum in the direction in 
%# which rows are counted
output = cumsum(output,1);

%# for fun, visualize the result
%# there's white whenever a note is on
imshow(output)
```

Comment: very interesting, thanks!  but how do I see the result as a new matrix, so that I can check it? The output visualisuation on my actual MIDI file says it is way too big (there are 88000 rows).

Comment: In other words, is there some way to view this output as an excel file?  Also, from what I can make out on the matlab output, I sometimes have -2 or -1 as results? I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: @Tom: the only reasons why `output` could contain negative values is that (1) there is a stop without a start, or (2) there are duplicate values for starts and stops - see my edit for how to fix #2. Also, to write to Excel, use `xlswrite('myFile.xls',output)`

Comment: I've noticed something else strange as well- which is the fault of the data. When a note repeats, the MIDI file shows a 0 for the note at that time, and then a 1 for the very same time, same note a few rows later. I think this is confusing the script.  On preview, you seem to have anticipated the problem! which bit of the script is changed?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, that is a problem for the code. However, assigning 'off' before assigning 'on' should fix the issue (I won't fix that in the code, since I don't want to retype all the comments).

Comment: @Jonas. Hi again. I've been trying to implement your script.  I tried just swapping around the order of the on and off parts of the script whcih seemed to solve the old issue, but now I'm getting cumulatively building positive numbers in the columns.  Sorry I'm probably being thick about this!

Comment: @Tom: Oh, now I understand your input data. Ok, the fix is easy: Add instead of replace values. See my edit where I add the minus ones (no need to swap parts of code anymore, btw).

Comment: @jonas. Thanks again, but whether the duplicate time/notes should be 1 or 0 depends on the order they are presented in the file- the true value should be the later one...  Actually hold that, it will always be 1, because it never says on and then off immediately.

Comment: @Tom: Yep, but a sequence of 1,0/1,0/1,0/1,0 should become 1,0,0,0,-1 before cumsum, so that it'll end up 1,1,1,1,0 in the end. That's what addition will do.

Comment: ok, awesome. I'll have to check it in a few minutes, but looks like a great solution!

Comment: @jonas. hello again. I found a problem where I have data like this. The script makes the row unique, so removes 1 of the 'on' rows. But this leaves an 'off' or 0 row as the first point, so creates minus-number errors. Is there any way to fix this?   384...1...71        
384...0...71    
384...1...71

Comment: on the 'unique' help file it indicates that adding 'first' might solve the problem, but I seem unable to make it work.

Comment: actually if only the last row gets removed, this will leave the final value as a 0, so that won't work anyway- I need to get rid of both the redundant rows.

Comment: @Tom: actually, the order of lines is not a problem for my solution. However, 1..0..1 should evaluate to 1, while with `unique`, it will become 1..0, and thus evaluates to 0.

Comment: @jonas. Sorry, that doesn't work. Isn't there some loop I could run to just remove the offending lines? I've tried multiplying column 1 with column 3, and then running a loop such that if the result matches another result minus-2 rows it will delete the rows, but it just keeps complaining. Help please!

Comment: @Tom: I have updated the solution to use `accumarray`, so it should work now.